# getting map with .includes(values of ARRAY)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

So I am trying to map my routes based on what roles they have. For instance my map routes.roles:["User","Admin"] or just ["Admin"]. And Current user has one or multiple roles. 
This works

```
let newRoutes = testRoutes.filter(route => {
      return route.roles.includes("Admin");
    });
```

but i need it instead of "Admin" to compare to each Value in currentUser.Roles, which is an array of string.
Please Help!!

Comment: so you can pass `User.Role` instead of hard coded `Admin`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter single or multiple roles using `filter()`

Example -

```js
let roles = ["User","Admin", "User2", "Admin2", "Manager"];
let res = roles.filter(role=>role==='Admin'?role:role==='User'?role:role==='Manager'?role:'')
console.log(res)
```